# Xcode: Storing API Secrets & IDs Securely

Tags: objective-c, security, encryption, api-key

I am developing an app and need a way to securely store API secrets and IDs. I understand that storing these strings directly within source-code is insecure as the code can be decompiled by hackers. I was wondering what the best way of hiding and securing these strings is and whether there is standard practise for doing such? I know this

From my own research I understand that hashing only allows a one-way encryption for verification of a string and that encryption allows two way encryption/decryption via the use of an encryption key. Therefore it may be necessary to hide the encrypted keys and their string's within a file.

Thanks

D

Comment: Who has given a -1 ? Its an important and intersting question of "How to store a secret during compile time and deliver it?" I am thinking of internal API keys, the user never will see, but need to be present at runtime.

Comment: you can see a discussion of your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525305/how-to-store-a-secret-api-key-in-an-applications-binary?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

The place to save keys and API secrets is the App Keychain.

The keychain is designed to store secrets in a secure encrypted manner, there is no better way in iOS.

See [iOS Keychain Services Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).
There are many source on SO of how to access the keychain.

Comment: You have to get the keys into the keychain firstly. So if it's a static API key this isn't a solution.