# TweePy - how to hide API key

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am building simple app which is using Twitter API. What I have to do to hide my Twitter app keys? For example, if I will put my program to the internet and somebody who look up to the code will know my consumer key, access token etc. And if I not include this information into my program, that it won't be work!

Comment: here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525305/how-to-store-a-secret-api-key-in-an-applications-binary) that you may find useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming by `putting on the internet` you mean publishing your code on github or such.

In that case you should always separate code and configuration. Put your API keys in an .ini file, i.e. config.ini, then load that file from python program using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Add configuration file to your **.gitignore** so it would not get added to the source control.

Comment: This is exactly that, what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Not a problem, if it helped you can set this answer as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're running on a Unix like system, one way to handle this is environment variables.

In your shell you can do this:

```
export TWITTER_API_KEY=yoursecretapikey
```

Note that you don't use quotes of any kind for this.

Then in your script:

```
import os
twitter_key = os.environ.get('TWITTER_API_KEY')
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But what happened if somebody will download my program and will try to run it? That environment variables will be set in that person OS too?

Comment: You can check to see if the variable is set using `if "TWITTER_API_KEY" in os.environ`. `os.environ` gets environment variables from any common OS.

Comment: I tried this and it was not retrievable within python and vanished from the unix environment variables after a reboot.