# where does the variables defined using "--dart-define" go and can we reverse engineer them?

Tags: flutter, dart, secret-key

I am building a flluter application.
I don't want to compromise my `secret_key` by putting it in the code, so I tried making a `.env` file and created an apk. Then I unzipped the apk and found my config file there. So now I am not doing that.

The next thing I tried is using `--dart-define` variable declarations to put my `secret_key` while building the app and I am accessing it using

```
const secret = String.fromEnvironment("secret_key");
```

Coming to the question, where do these variables go inside the dart code and is there a way to get them by reverse engineering.
Basically is it safe to put my secret key this way?

Comment: Yes its safe because  `--dart-define` variable you need to define in build command and that is not saved any where in code at the time of build generation these keys used.

Comment: If your code needs `secret_key` at runtime, then it is not strictly safe.  Anything your code can do, someone sufficiently determined can also do by examining your code.

Comment: @jamesdlin what do you mean by that? I didn't get it. 
My use case is to call an API using that secret key that's it. without it, I can not call the API.

Comment: I mean that what you're asking is, strictly speaking, impossible.  If code running on a client needs a fixed secret to operate, the client needs access to the secret, and someone sufficiently determined will be able to extract it from client-side code.  See [How to store a secret API key in an application's binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525305/)

Comment: Thanks, @jamesdlin. I got that. but what about `--dart-define` saving the variables which has no trace in code other than the binaries?

Comment: Well, using `--dart-define` avoids needing to hard-code your secrets and make them plainly visible to anyone who can read your source code (which is good), but it won't help against someone reverse-engineering your program (which is impossible).

Comment: so I can use that to at least avoid putting the key inside the code.

Answer (score 2):

From what I found, you can find the `--dart-define` variables in the **binary file** generated for each ABI, so **yes**, you can reverse-engineer it.

**How to try:**

1. Call the variable from your code with `String.fromEnvironment("ANIMAL")`.
2. Run `flutter build apk --dart-define=ANIMAL=Dog` to build for Android
3. Open the generated .APK file with a file archiver (7-Zip, for example) and navigate to `/lib/(ABI)/`
4. Open `/lib/(ABI)/libapp.so` file with a text editor or hex viewer and search for the value `Dog` and you will find it

**Observations:**

- If you don't use the variable in your code, it won't be added to the binary
- Using `--obfuscate` with `flutter build` won't help, because it doesn't obfuscate environment variables